# How to Hide Navigation Bar Permanently in Android

Tags: android, hide, show-hide, navigationbar

I am trying to hide navigation bar at bottom in my app.

With following code in my `onCreate` I can hide it. But when I press screen or press volume buttons it comes up again.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

How can I permanently hide navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I did it with using

`View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE` and

`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` flags same time.

It requires `4.4` but my `version is 4.2.2`.

*Thats why I couldn't do it before. Thank you all for your answers and consern.*

Comment: Hi, pls share the code on how did you manage to implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add this Code In to Your `onCreate()` Method it will work for you But android version 4.4 or higher

```
View decor_View = getWindow().getDecorView();

int ui_Options = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

decor_View.setSystemUiVisibility(ui_Options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public void FullScreencall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // 19 or above API
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        //For lower API versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView(); 
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

Call this method on your `onCreate`

Comment: I got an error saying cannot find symbol getWindow()